# npm install getting stopped when an error occurred

Tags: node.js, npm-install

npm install getting stopped when an error occurred

> ```
> npm ERR! 404  '@typescript-eslint/parser@^1.3.0' is not in the npm registry.
> npm ERR! 404 Your package name is not valid, because
> npm ERR! 404  1. name can only contain URL-friendly characters
> npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'angular-gettext-tools'
> ```

Please help

Comment: what happens if you try to install the following : `@typescript-eslint/parser`

Comment: it can be that you are behind a proxy which is not properly configured to handle e.g. slash symbol. Do you use any private npm registry?

Comment: Could yout provide your package.jsonif you have ? Or maybe the npm command ?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
npm install @typescript-eslint/parser --save-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

```
npm install @typescript-eslint/parser --save-dev
```

Then:
In your ESLint configuration file, set the parser property:

```
  {
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser"
}
```

For more info: https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-eslint-parser

Comment: Actually its accessing private npm repository URL which is

Not Found - GET https://abcc/repository/sample/@typescript-eslint%2fparser

Comment: @VinothMarieswaran Updated my answer. Old answer was for a replicated package

Answer (score 0):

i have added the below line in the ".npmrc" file, Issue solved then

```
@typescript-eslint:registry="https://registry.npmjs.org"
```

Thanks Guys for the suggestions